# Convert Django rest Api date time value to human readable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

my Django rest API returns time in a format that isn't human readable. For example: **2020-10-14T18:00:03.220930+01:00.**

I'd like to convert such values into human readable values in Javascript.For example: 2020-10-14, 6:03pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered passing the value into new Date() object converts it from ISO time to human readable time. for example:

`new Date('2020-10-14T18:00:03.220930+01:00')`

returns

**Wed Oct 14 2020 18:00:03 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)**